dml equivalent of python function isinstance
Is there an equivalent of the Python function isinstance in DML 1.4?
I would like to check if a DML object implements a particular template in DML code, and if so run logic on that object.
Didn't get a direct answer from checking the DML reference manual.

The question is incorrectly tagged as dml, which is some SQL thing unrelated to device modeling, this is likely why someone downvoted it. I think the question makes sense, and have posted a suggested edit.

There is not; however, there is a pattern you may leverage that will allow you to check if an object instantiates a specific template by leveraging params and in each declarations.
For an illustrative example, let's say you want to be able to tell if a specific register instantiates the read_only template. Then what you can do is:
template register_maybe_read_only {
    param is_read_only default false;
}

in each register { is register_maybe_read_only; }
in each (register_maybe_read_only, read_only) { param is_read_only = true; }

This will make it so every register in your model will have the is_read_only parameter, and that parameter will only be true if the register also instantiates read_only.
The above is good enough if the context in which you need the check is working with a compile-time reference to the object. If you're instead working with a value of a template type, such as what you're given inside a foreach loop on an each-in expression, then you will need to expand upon this pattern as follows:
template register_maybe_read_only is register {
    param is_read_only : bool;
    param is_read_only default false;
    shared method as_read_only() -> (read_only) default {
        assert false; // Caller must check 'is_read_only' before calling this
    }
}

template register_maybe_read_only_yes is (register_maybe_read_only, read_only) {
    param is_read_only = true;
    shared method as_read_only() -> (read_only) {
        return cast(this, read_only);
    }
}

in each register { is register_maybe_read_only; }
in each (register_maybe_read_only, read_only) { is register_maybe_read_only_yes; }

Then: if, for example, you want a loop like this:
foreach reg in (each register in (this)) {
    if (reg.is_read_only) { // Does not compile!
        ...
    } else { // If the reg is not read-only
        ...
    }
}

Then what you can do instead is this:
foreach reg in (each register_maybe_read_only in (this)) {
    if (reg.is_read_only) { // Compiles!
        local read_only reg_as_read_only = reg.as_read_only();
        ...
    } else { // If the reg is not read-only
        ...
    }
}

Due to the in each register, every register is also a register_maybe_read_only, so the loop will capture the same objects as previous, but now it also has the power to discern if the register instantiates read_only, and even convert the value to that template type if so.
Prior to Simics Base version 6.0.206 / 7.20.0, there was a DMLC bug that would cause the compiler to crash unless the override of as_read_only() inside register_maybe_read_only_yes were changed to not be declared shared. If you are using an older version of Simics 6 / 7, then this bug is rather nasty -- the override not being a shared implementation could cause bloat in generated C code and slow down compilation if the model contains a lot of read_only registers (in your case: objects that instantiate the desired template that you want to check).

This answer was originally written before the DMLC bug mentioned within it was addressed, and declared the as_read_only() override as not shared. It has now been updated to reflect that the bug has been fixed as of Simics Base version 6.0.206 / 7.20.0.

Assuming you have a template foo for registers, and you want to check if register instances can be cast to foo, I wanted to suggest the following approach:
dml 1.4;
template maybe_foo {
  shared method as_foo() -> (foo) throws default { throw; }
}
in each register { is maybe_foo; }
template foo is maybe_foo {
  shared method as_foo() -> (foo) throws { return this; }
}

Unfortunately, this currently causes the compiler to crash:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ecarsten/6/linux64/bin/dml/python/dml/dmlc.py", line 703, in main
    dev = process(devname, global_defs, top_tpl, defs)
  File "/home/ecarsten/6/linux64/bin/dml/python/dml/dmlc.py", line 91, in process
    structure.mkglobals(global_defs)
  File "/home/ecarsten/6/linux64/bin/dml/python/dml/structure.py", line 207, in mkglobals
    (dml.globals.templates, dml.globals.traits) = template.process_templates(
  File "/home/ecarsten/6/linux64/bin/dml/python/dml/template.py", line 353, in process_templates
    trait = dml.traits.process_trait(
  File "/home/ecarsten/6/linux64/bin/dml/python/dml/traits.py", line 112, in process_trait
    return mktrait(site, name, ancestors, methods, params, sessions, hooks,
  File "/home/ecarsten/6/linux64/bin/dml/python/dml/traits.py", line 350, in mktrait
    typecheck_method_override(
  File "/home/ecarsten/6/linux64/bin/dml/python/dml/traits.py", line 401, in typecheck_method_override
    if realtype(t0).cmp(realtype(t1)) != 0:
  File "/home/ecarsten/6/linux64/bin/dml/python/dml/types.py", line 110, in realtype
    t = realtype_shallow(t)
  File "/home/ecarsten/6/linux64/bin/dml/python/dml/types.py", line 101, in realtype_shallow
    raise DMLUnknownType(t)
dml.types.DMLUnknownType: Unknown type: foo

I managed to work around the crash with the following, which however comes at an extra cost in code size (one extra C trampoline in each register object):
dml 1.4;
template _maybe_foo {
  method _as_foo() -> (foo) throws default { throw; }
}
template maybe_foo is _maybe_foo {
    shared method as_foo() -> (foo) throws;
    method as_foo() -> (foo) throws {  return _as_foo(); }
}
in each register { is maybe_foo; }
template foo is _maybe_foo {
  method _as_foo() -> (foo) throws { return this; }
}


The crash mentioned in this answer has been addressed in Simics Base version 6.0.206 / 7.20.0.
